# Hibernate - Mapping association on un-related objects in xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have 2 classes:

- User
- RentedCar

  ```
  public class User implements Serializable{
      private String userName;
      private Integer userId;
      private String userParent;
  }

  public class RentedCar implements Serializable{
      private Date stopDate;
      private Date startDate;
      private String carName;
      private Integer carId;
      private Integer userId;   // Some userId from User.
  }
  ```

These classes have their respective `hbm.xml` files. The underlying tables are un-related. Which means that I know that the `userId` in `RentedCar` is associated with the `userId` in `User` but there is no PK/FK relationship between them. I need to add a `many-to-one` association between `RentedCar` and `User` and `one-to-many` association between `User` and `RentedCar`. How should I do this in the hbm.xml files ?

These are the xml mappings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="User" table="user">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="userName" column="user_name" type="string"/>
            <key-property name="userParent" column="user_parent" type="string"/>
        </composite-id>
        <property name="userId" column="user_id" type="int"></property>
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="RentedCar" table="rented_car">
        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="stopDate" column="stop_date" type="date" />
            <key-property name="carId" column="car_id" type="int" />
            <key-property name="userId" column="user_id" type="int" />
        </composite-id>
        <property name="startDate" column="start_date" type="date"></property>
        <property name="carName" column="car_name" type="float"></property>
    </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have something in your classes show that there is  one-to-many relationship in order to do this in hbm.xml files :

```
public class User implements Serializable{
    private String userName;
    private Integer userId;
    private String userParent;
    private Set<RentedCar> rentedCars;
}

public class RentedCar implements Serializable{
    private Date stopDate;
    private Date startDate;
    private String carName;
    private Integer carId;
    private User user; 
}
```

Then in RentedCar.hbm.xml you can inside  use :

```
<many-to-one name="user" class="User">
        <column name="userId" not-null="true"></column>
 </many-to-one>
```

And in User.hbm.xml :

```
<set name="rentedCars" table="rented_car" fetch="select">
     <key>
          <column name="userId" not-null="true"></column>
     </key>
     <one-to-many class=" RentedCar "/>
 </set>
```

This tutorial may help you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_one_to_many_mapping.htm

Comment: The above doesn't work as userId is not an id in the User table. Thus it throws a foreign key error.

Comment: Sorry , you call it user_id in "user" table and userId in "User" class @Viraj

Comment: I meant that userId is not part of the "id" in the hbm.xml mapping file.

Comment: I do not think it is enough to know that the userId in RentedCar is associated with the userId in User , I think these database tables should also know and then you should have foreign key , and this is the use of userId here.

Comment: and if it is not a primar key in user table then you can use a column which is part of your PK  as a FK(name or parent) rather than userId.

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, there is no relation between any column which is part of the composite key to the RentedCar table.